# Symfony : render collection with custom protoype

Tags: symfony, twig

Situation : I have an entity CompetenceGroupe (with attributes "titre" and "competence_items") and an entity "CompetenceItem" (with attributes "libelle" and "niveau"). A CompetenceGroupe can have multiple CompetenceItem, so it's a collection.

For that, I have created my own prototype to customize the render of the collections. It's working fine, but I have a problem when I want to edit an existing CompetenceGroupe, because the childrens CompetenceItem are not rendered in the form.

I show you my code.

CompetenceGroupeType

```
class CompetenceGroupeType extends AbstractType
{
    /**
     * @param FormBuilderInterface $builder
     * @param array $options
     */
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder
            ->add('titre')
            ->add('competence_items', CollectionType::class, array(
                'entry_type'   => CompetenceItemType::class,
                'allow_add'    => true,
                'allow_delete' => true,
                'label' => false,
                'prototype' => true,

            ))
            //->add('save',      SubmitType::class)
            ;
    }

    /**
     * @param OptionsResolver $resolver
     */
    public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults(array(
            'data_class' => 'AppBundle\Entity\CompetenceGroupe',
        ));
    }
}
```

CompetenceItemType

```
class CompetenceItemType extends AbstractType
{
    /**
     * @param FormBuilderInterface $builder
     * @param array $options
     */
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder
            ->add('libelle')
            ->add('niveau', EntityType::class, array(
                'class' => 'AppBundle:CompetenceNiveau',
                'choice_label' => 'libelle_competence_niveau_fr',
                'required' => false,
            ))
            ;
    }

    /**
     * @param OptionsResolver $resolver
     */
    public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults(array(
            'data_class' => 'AppBundle\Entity\CompetenceItem',
        ));
    }
}
```

The form for CompetenceGroupe

```
{{ form_start(formAddCompetence, { 'attr': {'class': 'formCompetenceAdd'} }) }}

    <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
        <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">{{ libelleCategorie }}</h4>
    </div>

    <div class="modal-body">

        {{ dump(formAddCompetence) }}

        <h4><span class="label label-default">Les champs marqués d'un astérisque sont obligatoires.</span></h4>

        {# render the task's only field: description #}
        {{ form_row(formAddCompetence.titre) }}

        <div id="competence_groupe_competence_items"
             data-prototype="
             {% filter escape %}
                 {{ include('espaceUtilisateur/forms/prototypes/competence_item_prototype.html.twig', { 'item': formAddCompetence.competence_items.vars.prototype }) }}
             {% endfilter %}">

        </div>

        {{ form_widget(formAddCompetence._token) }}

        <br>
        <a href="#" id="add_category" class="btn btn-default">Ajouter une catégorie</a>

    </div>

    <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Annuler</button>

        {% if objectCompetence.idCompetenceGroupe is not empty %}
            {{ form_widget(formAddCompetence.edit) }}
            <input type="hidden" name="idCompetenceGroupe" id="idCompetenceGroupe" value="{{ objectCompetence.idCompetenceGroupe }}">
        {% else %}
            {{ form_widget(formAddCompetence.save) }}
        {% endif %}
    </div>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        // On récupère la balise <div> en question qui contient l'attribut « data-prototype » qui nous intéresse.
        var $container = $('div#competence_groupe_competence_items');

        // On définit un compteur unique pour nommer les champs qu'on va ajouter dynamiquement
        var index = $container.find(':input').length;

        // On ajoute un nouveau champ à chaque clic sur le lien d'ajout.
        $('#add_category').click(function(e) {
            addCategory($container);

            e.preventDefault(); // évite qu'un # apparaisse dans l'URL
            return false;
        });

        // On ajoute un premier champ automatiquement s'il n'en existe pas déjà un (cas d'une nouvelle annonce par exemple).
        if (index == 0) {
            //console.log('index');
            addCategory($container);
        } else {
            // S'il existe déjà des catégories, on ajoute un lien de suppression pour chacune d'entre elles
            $container.children('div').each(function() {
                addDeleteLink($(this));
            });
        }

        // La fonction qui ajoute un formulaire CategoryType
        function addCategory($container) {
            // Dans le contenu de l'attribut « data-prototype », on remplace :
            // - le texte "__name__label__" qu'il contient par le label du champ
            // - le texte "__name__" qu'il contient par le numéro du champ
            var template = $container.attr('data-prototype')
                            .replace(/__name__label__/g, 'Catégorie n°' + (index+1))
                            .replace(/__name__/g,        index)
                    ;


            // On crée un objet jquery qui contient ce template
            var $prototype = $(template);

            // On ajoute au prototype un lien pour pouvoir supprimer la catégorie
            addDeleteLink($prototype);

            // On ajoute le prototype modifié à la fin de la balise <div>
            $container.append($prototype);

            // Enfin, on incrémente le compteur pour que le prochain ajout se fasse avec un autre numéro
            index++;
        }

        // La fonction qui ajoute un lien de suppression d'une catégorie
        function addDeleteLink($prototype) {

            // Création du lien
            var $deleteLink = $('<div><a href="#" class="btn btn-danger">Supprimero</a></div>');

            // Ajout du lien
            $prototype.last().append($deleteLink);

            // Ajout du listener sur le clic du lien pour effectivement supprimer la catégorie
            $deleteLink.click(function(e) {
                $prototype.remove();

                e.preventDefault(); // évite qu'un # apparaisse dans l'URL
                return false;
            });
        }
    });
</script>
```

And my custom prototype

```
<div class="form-group">
    {{ form_label(item.libelle, "libelle a", {'label_attr': {'class': 'col-md-3 control-label'}}) }}
    {{ form_errors(item.libelle) }}
    <div>
        {{ form_widget(item.libelle) }}
    </div>
</div>

<div class="form-group">
    {{ form_label(item.niveau, "niveau a", {'label_attr': {'class': 'col-md-3 control-label'}}) }}
    {{ form_errors(item.niveau) }}
    <div>
        {{ form_widget(item.niveau) }}
    </div>
</div>
```

Maybe my problem is that the rendering of the existing CompetenceItem for a CompetenceGroupe is missing. Maybe I have to loop on it for render them... As you can see, I'm lost ...

Thanks in advance for your advices !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way you do it look really wrong so I don't think anybody will spend hours to find a tricky way to fix your issue. You should use a [form theme](https://symfony.com/doc/current/form/form_customization.html) instead of creating the prototype by yourself.

1) In CompetenceGroupeType.php, add the following method:

```
public function getBlockPrefix()
{
    return 'competence_group';
}
```

2) wrap code in competence_item_prototype.html.twig by:

```
{% block competence_group_widget %}

    <div class="form-group">
        (...)
    </div>

{% endblock %}
```

Also replace `item` by `form`.

3) in your view, before calling `{{ form_start(formAddCompetence, {...} }) }}` function, add the following:

```
{% form_theme formAddCompetence 'espaceUtilisateur/forms/prototypes/competence_item_prototype.html.twig' %}
```

And a bit of spam for a plugin I created, but for the right purpose :) you can have a look to https://symfony-collection.fuz.org that provides many examples on how to create form collections.

Comment: @ Alain Tiemblo thanks for the response. I have use your exemple, but still have no items when a CompetenceGroupe have existing Competence Items. What part of the code show them in the twig view ?

Comment: You should use `{{ form_row(formAddCompetence.ompetence_items) }}`

Comment: Still the same, maybe I have add this in the wrong place ... Note that my part of code 'code' <div id="competence_groupe_competence_items"
             data-prototype="
             {% filter escape %}
                 {{ include('espaceUtilisateur/forms/prototypes/competence_item_prototype.html.twig', { 'form': formAddCompetence.competence_items.vars.prototype }) }}
             {% endfilter %}">

        </div>  'code' is still in my CompetenceGroupe form. Do i Have to delete it ?

Comment: I have put the getBlockPrefix function in the CompetenceItemType (childrens), and everything works perfectly. Thank you so much !